# Split the given date into days

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am writing a Stored Procedure. Basically i need take year and month information from user and doing something. But my problem is i don't detect given month has how many days. Let me explain with example;

User give me year and month as i said;

```
@year = 2015

@month = 07
```

So i must create rows like;

```
2015-07-01

2015-07-02

.....

2015-07-31
```

My plan is adding these rows one by one to another temp table.

Last status of my SP is;

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Usp_CreateStats]
(
 @Year VARCHAR (40),
 @Month VARCHAR (40)
 )
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @StartTime VARCHAR (10)
DECLARE @EndTime VARCHAR (10)
SET @StartTime = '00:00:00'
SET @EndTime = '23:59:59'

DECLARE @Peoples TABLE (name VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @Peoples (name) select distinct name from USERINFO

DECLARE @Dates TABLE (date VARCHAR(50))



END
```

I hope explained correctly.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: My first thought would be to create a tally table with dates, and joining that based on year and month.

Comment: http://sqlhints.com/2014/02/03/how-to-get-day-month-year-and-time-part-from-datetime-in-sql-server/

Comment: Why are all your variable VARCHAR instead of INT or DATETIME?

Comment: Calendar table. Set-based awesomeness.Here's just one example script to create one: http://gvee.co.uk/files/sql/dbo.numbers%20&%20dbo.calendar.sql

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the year and month variables to `int` data type, 
the name of your date column to `dates_date`, and used [`convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) and a while loop with [`dateadd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function to populate the `@dates` table:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Usp_CreateStats]
(
 @Year int,
 @Month int
 )
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @StartTime VARCHAR (10),
        @EndTime VARCHAR (10),
        @Date date
SET @StartTime = '00:00:00'
SET @EndTime = '23:59:59'

SET @Date = CONVERT(date, right('0000' + cast(@year as char(4)), 4) + right('00' + cast(@month as char(2)), 2)+ '01', 112)

DECLARE @Peoples TABLE (name VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @Peoples (name) select distinct name from USERINFO

DECLARE @Dates TABLE (dates_date date)

while month(@date) = @Month    
begin
    insert into @Dates (dates_date) values (@Date)
    set @Date = dateadd(day, 1, @date)
end

END
```

Comment: A `WHILE` loop is not necessary here.

Comment: I agree that a tally table like in your answer is a more elegant solution. however I don't have enough experience with tally tables, so...

Comment: That's okay. But I suggest you start reading on it. One of the best tool I've ever learned.

Comment: @ZoharPeled here is an excellent article on the topic. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Answer (score 1):

To generate the dates based on `@year` and `@month`, you can use a [**Tally Table**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/).

```
DECLARE @year   INT = 2015,
        @month  INT = 7

DECLARE @startDate DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, @month - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, @year - 1900, CAST('19000101' AS DATE)))

;WITH Tally (n) AS
(   -- 100 rows
    SELECT TOP(31) 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n)
)
SELECT
    DATEADD(DAY, N-1, @startDate)
FROM Tally t
WHERE
    DATEADD(DAY, N-1, @startDate) < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @startDate)
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/2296/0)

---

Note: Use the appropriate data type for your variables. In this case, `@month` and `@year` should be `INT`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive CTE.

```
Declare @Year as varchar(5) = '2015'
Declare @Month as varchar(5) = '05'

Declare @DateOfMonth as DateTime =  @Month + '-01-' + @Year

Declare @startdate datetime, @enddate datetime

SET @startdate = DATEADD(s,0,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@DateOfMonth),0))
SET @enddate = DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@DateOfMonth)+1,0))
SET @enddate = DATEADD(day,-1,@enddate)

;With DateSequence( Date ) as
(
    Select @startdate as Date
        union all
    Select dateadd(day, 1, Date)
        from DateSequence
        where Date < @enddate
)

--select result
Select * from DateSequence option (MaxRecursion 1000)
```

Comment: I advise against using recursive CTE as this is a form of hidden RBAR. Read this [**article**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/) by Jeff Moden for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Month int= 7 
Declare @Year int = 2015
Declare @MonthStart date = CAST(@Year  as varchar(4)) +  Right('00' +    Cast(@Month as varchar(2)), 2)  + '01'


DECLARE @DaysInMonth int = (SELECT
                    datediff(day, dateadd(day, 1-day(@MonthStart),     @MonthStart),
                    dateadd(month, 1, dateadd(day, 1-day(@MonthStart), @MonthStart))))

Declare @Dates TABLE (date date) 

DECLARE @Counter int = 0 
WHILE @Counter < @DaysInMonth 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @Dates SELECT DATEADD(Day, @Counter,  @MonthStart)

SET @Counter = @Counter + 1 
END
```

Comment: I was a bit slow on the draw here. Zohar Peled's solution is more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 0):

CTE you can use:

```
DECLARE @year               INT = 2015,
        @month              INT = 7,
        @first_day_of_month DATETIME,
        @last_day_of_month  DATETIME 

select @first_day_of_month = cast(cast(@year as varchar(4))+'/'+cast(@month as varchar(2))+'/'+'01' as date)
select @last_day_of_month = dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,@first_day_of_month)+1,0)-1

;with mycte as 
(
select @first_day_of_month as src
union all
select dateadd(dd,1,src) from mycte
where src < @last_day_of_month

)select * from mycte
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Recursive CTE,

```
DECLARE @year  VARCHAR(4) = '2015',
        @month VARCHAR(2)= '02',
        @date  DATETIME

SET @date= CONVERT(DATETIME, @year + '-' + @month + '-01');

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT @date AS dt
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Dateadd(dd, 1, dt) AS dt
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  dt < Dateadd(dd, -1, Dateadd(mm, Datediff(mm, 0, @date) + 1, 0)))
SELECT *
FROM   cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another (faster) tally solution:

```
DECLARE @year   INT = 2015,
        @month  INT = 7

DECLARE @start datetime = dateadd(m, (@year- 1900) * 12 + 7, -31)

SELECT TOP(datediff(d, @start, dateadd(m, 1, @start))) 
  dateadd(d, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) - 1, @start)
FROM 
  (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
   CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
convert(varchar,OrderDate,111)='2015-07-01'
```

Comment: can you please explain how this answers this question? OP wants to get dates based on year and month