# SQL: Can't insert a date loop into a column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
id: PK bigint
RatePercent: decimal(4, 4)
DateRange: date
```

I am trying to populate the table as follows:

- RatePercentage with all of them 0.12
- Date starting from '01-01-2015' to '12-31-2099'

Unfortunately with my query it won't do that and it keeps saying that

> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

I haven't assigned an int datatype asides from the id bigint. I'm a bit confused.

Here is my query so far:

```
DECLARE @Date Date
SET @Date = '01-01-2015'

WHILE @Date <= '12-31-2099'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[IMF_Main_VATHistory] (VATRate, VATDate)
    VALUES (0.12, @Date + 1);
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll advise against using any loop-based or **RBAR** solution. You can do this using a set-based approach with the help of a [**Tally Table**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/).

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE
DECLARE @endDate DATE

SET @startDate  = '20150101'
SET @endDate = '20991231';


WITH E1(N) AS(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
),
E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b),
E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b),
E8(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E4 b),
Tally(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF(DAY, @startDate, @endDate) + 1)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM E8
)
INSERT INTO IMF_Main_VATHistory(RatePercent, DateRange)
SELECT 
    0.02, DATEADD(DAY, N-1, @startDate)
FROM Tally
```

It's faster compared to using `CURSOR`s or `WHILE` loops.

Comment: So, I would need to create a temporary table(tally) for this procedure?

Comment: No need, you can create it on the fly. The cascaded CTEs do that for you.

Comment: Try both method, mine and the `WHILE` loops and you can see for yourself which is faster.

Comment: Yeah, its running the loop right now. I won't break it yet. But I'll tinker on your procedure as well. Then Choose the best answer for which one is faster.

Comment: Okay then. BTW, I'm Pinoy too. =)

Comment: It might take you more time to write the code for this rather than the actual execution, just to run a script that looks like it's going to need to be ran only once. But I'm not saying this is not right, I totally agree with set-based approach rather than **RBAR**.

Comment: Well, the loop failed and only made repeats of 2015-01-02. So I stopped it. I'm trying out your procedure now. If this works then you get a beer with the best answer (beer, if you are near)

Comment: I guess I'll have my beer then.=)

Comment: @JoshuaMasangcay The loop failed and you ran out of memory because there wasn't any actual incrementation of the value of the variable, so you had an infinite loop there. Just curious on the performance, run the script again, now.

Comment: Your procedure worked well and fast. @wewesthemenace. finished before I could fully lift my finger on the F5 key. I will tinker the functions used though. You deserve a beer! :)

Comment: why use a where statement ? All you need is TOP(datediff(d, '2015-01-01', '2099-12-31') + 1)

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, yup. That's clever. =)

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu's right. But still the Tally Table outperforms the `WHILE` loop.

Comment: answered a very [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31561153/split-the-given-date-into-days/31563958#31563958) question yesterday(so did you). Not a fan of looping. That is for different code languages

Comment: @wewesthemenace No doubt about that.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Date Date
SET @Date = '01-01-2015'

WHILE @Date <= '12-31-2099'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[IMF_Main_VATHistory] (VATRate, VATDate)
    VALUES (0.12, DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Date));

    SET @Date = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Date);
END
```

You can't issue a direct addition to a `DATE` datatype, in SQL Server (for reference, I think you can in Oracle). You have to use functions in order to modify a `DATE`/`DATETIME` variable (or column).

Here is an example [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/2338).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in you "@Date + 1" I think - The SQL-Server likes to try and convert to INT :)

Use [DATEADD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) that should work

```
DECLARE @Date Date
SET @Date = '01-01-2015'

WHILE @Date <= '12-31-2099'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[IMF_Main_VATHistory] (VATRate, VATDate)
    VALUES (0.12, @Date);
    SET @Date = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Date);
END
```

Comment: your solution will not give the correct answer. You are inserting 31046 identical dates. I am not a fan of looping in sql. It can almost always be avoided.

Comment: Yeah - i agree, But the question was how to fix "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int", so didn't use time to make an optimization, just an answer to the problem.